# How to scrape executed JavaScript without opening browser?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have been using Selenium to scroll and scrape from web pages that need JavaScript to be executed. Now I want to scrape pages without browser opening and for that reason I tried doing this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/bin/chromedriver.exe", options=op)
header =  {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"
                      " AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36"}
link = (
    "https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/303-E-57th-St-APT-44G-New-York-NY-10022/2076710336_zpid/"
)
response = requests.get(link)
webpage = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

The problem is that JavaScript is not being executed so the information I need is not loaded. How can I do that with headless Chrome and scroll through the page when the browser is not launched?

Comment: [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer)

Comment: Selenium https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/